# Evaluating a Property value on one line versus if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error (Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement) when using this code below.

```
decimal _percentagefootervalue;

public decimal PercentageFooterValue 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return this._percentagefootervalue;
    }
    set
    {
        this._percentagefootervalue = value;
    }
}
......
//error here
PercentageFooterValue == 100 ? lblPercentText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black : lblPercentText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Now, I can definitely use this block of code below and move on with life.  However, after checking around online, I still wasn't understanding what I'm doing wrong and would still like to know how it could work on one line if it is possible.

```
//works
if (PercentageFooterValue == 100)
{
   lblPercentText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
else
{
   lblPercentText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lblPercentText.ForeColor = PercentageFooterValue == 100 ? System.Drawing.Color.Black : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Statements** are fundament constructs of C# language(any language). Your C# statement is incorrect. Refer below the msdn guide on c# statements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx